# Set up user inbox service with Phoenix and RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, phoenix-framework

I am trying to set up a messaging system similar to LinkedIn for my app.  I am using Phoenix Framework and RethinkDB for persistence.  I am using RethinkDB instead of the default Postgres because the site is very fluid right now and in its infancy.  I can't really lock in a firm schema and relationships with things more than likely going to change as the app matures.  I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to set up the documents and fields for the database, and leverage Phoenix to create the proper form field to accept an array of recipients.  I would like to set it up with the following guidelines:

1. A User can create a message.
2. The message can be sent to one or more people.
3. A message can be saved as a draft.
4. The message can be replied to with the previous messages attached as a chain.

The main issues I am having are with collecting multiple recipients with form fields, and setting up the database to support the above mentioned guidelines.  If someone could get me started and on the right track, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just prototyping and getting to know the framework you might be better off with Postgres because it's so well supported. Migrations are there for a reason so you won't be stuck with a schema just because you are using Postgres. You should create data models that represent the problem prior to selecting a database, or at least treat it as a separate concern.

The form is going to be generated from a changeset. When using Rethink, changesets will be used for generation and validation but will not be applied the way they are with postgres. Start with a User model and a Message model. Have a "published" field in the Message model and it should be represented by a checkbox in the generated form.